What type of firearm is ideal in zero gravity infantry asteroid combat?
My world is similar to the cancelled game Boundary where astronauts shoot at each other in order to gain control of space stations or asteroids. They have special spacesuits with thrusters that allow them to zoom from asteroid to asteroid and with extra oxygen in case of leakage.
Aiming in 3-dimensions while flying around is a lot more difficult than aiming in real life. So combat generally takes place within 100 meter ranges. That said, there isn't any gravity or wind in outer space so bullets fly straight. Would a modern rifle, shotgun, light machine gun, or pistol be the ideal weapon for infantry space combat?

Photographers know that the absolute best camera is the one which you actually have with you. For the same reason, the best firearm is the firearm which you are actually carrying.

Keep in mind that, unlike many sci fi depictions, the average distance between asteroids is about a million kilometres, or roughly 3 x the distance from Earth to its moon.  This makes trips between asteroids take a minimum of days, more likely weeks, while the asteroids themselves can be hundreds of km in diameter with correspondingly long engagement ranges in order to fight for control of the surface.

You might want to put your astronauts inside of some kind of structure, otherwise the answer is "radar guided missile" or "laser the size of a Prius" fired from hundreds of kilometers away.

Re-reading: is your question: "My guys have modern infantry rifles, shotguns, LMGs, and pistols, which one/s would be effective under the above constraints?"

VTC:Too Story-Based. "Ideal" or any other superlative (e.g. best, worst, greatest, etc.) makes this question 100% and instantly too story-based as it depends on the specific conditions and circumstances of any fight (what cover is there? Exactly what is the tech we're dealing with? What are the dispositions of opposing forces? Etc.) I can rationalize any weapon you choose by changing the story circumstances. Worse is the claim aiming in 3-dimensions while flying around is a lot more difficult than aiming in real life. You need to research aerial dog-fighting.

@JBH I admit that based on my experience with real shooting ranges and fictional dogfights, I suspect that OP is right that it’s harder while flying around in 3D.

@DanielB I don't doubt you, I just suspect the OP hasn't thought the issue through and therefore hasn't performed due diligence research. Real life has 3D aiming and shooting. Is it harder than 2D(ish) aiming and shooting? Of course... but there's little practical difference between the restrictions of space and a space helmet and a plane and a pilot's helmet. In fact, I would expect the problems faced by the space combatants to have already been fundamentally solved by today's fighter planes. What's the ideal solution? Francis Nowlan solved this in 1928 ... (*Continued*)

... in his book Armageddon 2419 A.D. - rockets - and that's been proven to be true with modern 3D combat (fighter planes) using missiles. The closest any military came to implementing this as a sidearm was the gyrojet. Why wasn't it more popular? Recoil is less of an issue on the ground and making a tracking missile that small was impractical.

@DanielB Also, let's be honest, this question isn't sensible. Space combat would never take this form. Humans in space suits at a technology level where drones are more practical, cost effective, and experience fewer restrictions based on the selected weapon, simply wouldn't exist. This idea is a bit of fun 1950s throwback, which makes the question nonsensical. Every weapon has its pros and cons and the fun of a well-written story is that both the pros and the cons are presented as part of the combat experience. Thus, any weapon can work. Which is cheapest? Is that not ideal?

VTC since no clarification for a couple of days to remove story-based-ness. I will remove my VTC if clarification is made.

Air Rifles
To avoid giving away the shooter's position (as likely to be a problem in space as on the ground), limit disorientation and loss of targeting, and avoid issues with powder gas deposits on anything near the muzzle, a recoilless cold gas gun (aka PreCompressed Pneumatic) would be ideal.
Air guns have been used in military and hunting applications since the very early 19th century (Lewis and Clark famously had a Girandoni air rifle with them on their expedition to explore the then-new Louisiana Purchase and penetrate to the Pacific, and used it regularly for hunting because it didn't deplete the limited amount of powder they could carry for their flintlocks).
In an asteroid field, the expelled gas would be visible (at least in direct sunlight), but only for the time it takes the gas and ice fog to disperse -- a second or so.  With recoilless venting, the gun wouldn't kick the user all over the place, and there's no problem with power (look on YouTube for air gun videos -- modern air guns can take large game like bison at reasonable ranges, and without air resistance and local gravity the range is limited only by ability to aim and predict the movement of the target).

An air-rifle gives just as much recoil for its energy as a bullet.  Also, IR stealth is a lot harder in space, so using a cool register weapon is not nearly as helpful as it is on Earth because your space marines will be too warm to hide. Even on Earth, the advantages of bullets out weigh air guns, and I don't see this actually solving any new problems because you are in space.  But, the ice might create some new ones.

@Nosajimiki Hence why I specified recoilless -- as in using part of the propelling gas to offset the momentum of the bullet and gas that leaves the muzzle.  BTW, a "bullet" is the projectile; I think you mean "firearm".

Making an air rifle recoilless like that would mean expelling 2x as much energy which air rifles already struggle with.  Because air tanks are bigger and heavier for their potential energy, you could make your weapon stronger and fire more rounds by using a chemical rocket to the same effect.  Also, the projectile is called a slug, a bullet is a self contained slug and chemical propellant I was referring to the difference of using chemical vs compressed air to fire a slug.  That said, I don't think firearms or airguns are best, just that firearms are better.

Thread the needle
What you want are flechettes, or needles. Tiny, thin projectiles, each massing milligrams. Without air resistance to slow them down or make them tumble, they hit with effectively the same speed as they leave the barrel, and a needle puts as much weight as possible behind as thin of a cross section as possible, to maximize impact depth.
Each 'bullet' will consist of a bundle of these needles in a sabot. On leaving the barrel, the sabot breaks apart, making the spinning bundle of needles separate. They saturate a specific area, guaranteeing a 'hit' within a certain radius.
Recoil will not be a meaningful factor. If they have space suits with thrusters, those will be programmed to counteract recoil and keep the shooter steady.

+1 last paragraph is the key factor - weapons with recoil are fine so long as the thrusters are integrated with the weapon.

I've always thought that a sabot comes apart because of drag though the air. Would the design of the space sabot need to differ?

@Tashus just give it spin and centrifugal force can break it apart / disperse the needles.

Besides discarding the sabot, atmosphere plays a huge part in stabilizing the fins of flechettes as they travel to the target. I would let them shoot me with this weapon at 20m away, knowing that in the vacuum the flechettes will drift away and scatter so quickly the possibilites of being hit are close to zero. Make it 8m away if the gun is riffled.

Also consider that the lower the mass of the projectile the cheaper and more efficient it is to bring ammo into space. This is definitely the correct aswer.

Little bullets that move forever compromising every combatant indiscriminately and growing more dense with every shot. Eeek!

@JBH like the somme but without poison gas because space itself is already lethal!

@JBH Space is BIG! If you're standing next to an asteroid, you probably aren't close enough to see the next nearest asteroid. The chances of being hit by an asteroid by accident is almost zero, and there are millions of asteroids. You won't have to worry much about stray bullets until there are a lot more more bullets than asteroids.

@Robyn Space is indeed big! But the space where personal infantry combat is taking place isn't. If your opponent is so far away that you need enhanced optics and tracking just to see them then flechettes are entirely out. They'd take too long to travel to the opponent and spread out so much that maybe only one would hit the mark. I like this idea, I think it would make a whale of a good story... but only if the disadvantages are also part of the story. Two platoons of soldiers all using this kind of weapon would create a veritable snowstorm of deadly needles flying every which way.

@JBH re space, outside would be under fire from enemy ships, while the inside would be the ground for main infantry combat. And inside we have walls in every direction, so no or a few uncontrolled rounds, anything else would be absorbed by walls.

@Vesper Huh? It sounds like you're describing combat on a station or the interior of a large space ship, but that's not what the OP described. No walls. 100 meter diameter fighting range. Very high potential for harm from friendly fire regardless the weapon save for guided rocketry... but flechettes in that circumstance would be like braving a sand storm. Although now that I think about it, walls (especially in space) don't absorb ordinance. There would be ricochets, making everything worse. Yes?

@JBH yes indeed, see my frame challenge. The problem with the story is that it's unreal, any offense needs a base, thus a ship, a ship needs weapons, thus barely an infantry combat on the surface. Defense might sit under the surface and only have holes for communication, which are defendable and can be possibly concealed from the outside fire, thus infantry goes in.

@Vesper  Ah... I apologize. I didn't realize you were commenting from the perspective of your answer. Cheers!

"each massing milligrams" A typical sewing needle weighs about 1 gram.  If your needles were this small, they would have to be so stupidly thin they would crumple and tumble under the force of acceleration.  You've basically described a confetti cannon.  Keep in mind that spacesuits can already resist micro-meteors; so, any projectile that relies on low mass high speed mechanics is unlikely to be effective against even an "unarmored" space suit. Flechettes might be viable, but would probably need to weigh at least 3-4 grams each just to penetrate a regular space suit.

@Nosajimiki I don't know how I missed this, but no, a sewing needle absolutely does not weigh a gram, and I'm at a loss where such a number might have come from. A 1 gram, 5cm long needle would have to be nearly 2mm thick to mass that much. I just weighed a pile of sewing needles I had on hand, and it took about 20-22 to add up to a gram.

@DanielB It is worth noting that sewing needles vary a LOT. Your average milliner's needle pack contains needles ranging from 40.5x0.53mm to 69x1.83mm with weighs of about 0.070-1.43 grams if made of steel.  So, the only common sewing needles that would be about that light would be aluminum #8, 9, or 10s.  But, your average steel milliner's needle (which is what most people mean when they say sewing needle) is 0.75g.

...That said, you may mean straight pins. Most people don't have 20 sewing needles just lying around to weight, but they would have that many straight pins.  They tend to range from 19x0.4mm to 50x0.8mm with weighs of about 0.019g to 0.197g if made of steel with your most common style being a #20 fine pin @ 25x0.6mm weighing 0.055g  which would make your measurement of ~20/gram make a lot more since.

All that said, my comment about it being a confetti cannon remains true for an even bigger reason than I originally considered.  Flechettes need an atmosphere and fins for stability, or they need a sabot that can engage a rifled barrel to spin it limmiting you to one flechette per shot.  In the vacuum of space, you will not be able to keep them from tumbling wildly so those that do hit a target will not hit point first making them way less effective than firing a larger number of small round pellets like a normal shotgun.

@Nosajimiki 1. Nope, I definitely meant (and weighed) steel sewing needles, in a bulk assortment of sizes, which I pulled out of an emergency sewing kit. And yes, I’m aware they vary in size, but since the ones I weighed were big enough that I would not want them shoved through my body, I think they’ll do fine, size wise. 2. Yes, I specified a “spinning bundle”, so the sabot is rifled. 3. As far as I know, the reason projectiles tumble is atmosphere. I might be missing something, but I can’t think of why they’d tumble in a vacuum, even if I had not specified they are spun, which I did.

Emergency sewing kit needles tend to be much smaller than standard sewing needles, so that makes since. They are made to take up as little space as possible, but bend easily with regular use. As for your sabots, spin and rotation are not the same in this context.  If the sabot does not spin around its central axis, it will not create a stabilizing gyroscopic rotation. Spinning the shell will just increase how much you scatter your needles.

Gyrojet.
YouTube Video
Wikipedia article
"Every action has an equal and opposite reaction." - The Woolthorp Cyder-Maker's Marketing Board.
Firing a gun whilst performing delicate zero-g maneuvers won't help you maintain stability in zero-G. It'll likely make you tumble like a drunken gymnast.
Self-propelled rounds don't give you that kick as they work like tiny rockets - a bit like a shoulder-mounted RPG, Bazooka, AT4, Javelin etc., but with a design and rate of fire more like a repeater-riffle.
Self-propelled and self-guided smart-ammunition would give even more scope, even potentially allowing targets to be concealed from line of sight. (Courtesy of DWKraus's comment).

Or its more modern, laser-guided, 40mm big brother, the "Pike".  Would need to be adapted to use vectored thrust for steering instead of fins, but would definitely let you push out further than just 100m.

With enough tech, and big enough rounds, these could be tiny guided missiles seeking out opponents like tiny hunter-seekers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_bullet

Right, I'm having that! Thanks @DWKraus

Given the need for reactionless firing, and the reality that they'll need to hit something from miles away, I'm thinking that this is the only reasonable answer. They wouldn't really have a gun, they'd have a backpack full of knife missiles, with some kind of guidance. This would be the case even if the missile itself was a gun that fired when the missile was close enough to aim.

@DWKraus You say "big enough rounds," but we're obviously in future-tech-land here. If Asimov can believably (or, at least, entertaininly) present nuclear-powered personal shields as small as a pendant (Foundation series) then I'm ready to enjoy a story that promotes a pencil-sized thermal-tracking smart missile.

@RobertRapplean Definitely while out in space at least.  The firing doesn't necessarily have to be reactionless since you're burning the same amount of fuel either way whether you use a less-efficient recoilless launcher or run your suit jets to counter the recoil. But if you put all the fuel on the projectile you get a longer span of guided flight, and that's key to hitting things at orbital distances.  Now, presumably they're fighting over something. So what weapons make sense inside a ship or station might be different. But it won't be lasers unless they're over 80% efficient. ;)

Forgot to say, thanks @Perkins Self-propelled and computer guided seems to way to go for sure.

I'm no expert, but Shadiversity made an excellent video on swords in space (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiEJGFTdHj8) that brings up this point. Swords, or another weapon that's less reliant on the 'kickback' force of propulsion, but can still very much puncture the only layer between you and the unforgiving void, raise a point of interest for space battles without drunken gymnast battles.

@JBH In the realm of personal ammunition, a pencil is huge. I'm talking relatively.

@DWKraus I'm remembering a bad 80s movie with smart bullets. I can't remember the title, just that the movie made its point by shifting to the bullet's POV once discharged. My point? The idea of size-doesn't-matter guided missile personal firearms is old hat in SciFi and it's certainly not unbelievable that a future guided missile that could take out a single space suit is only the size of, say, a .22LR bullet, which is why I upvoted this answer.

@Asterion Swinging a sword still has the same amount of recoil in proportion to the amount of energy you're throwing around.  You just have an opportunity to reclaim that momentum if you miss.  If you hit your target though, half the energy is going into them, and half is going into you, just like shooting a gun.  Try swinging a sword around while standing on ice if you care to experiment.  It'll be like that, but with a full 6 degrees of freedom to make it worse.

Recoilless rifles
Newton gave us a rather oppressive law: Actio = Reactio. Or "For every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction."
This tyrannical law tells us we need to throw something back to stay where we are in 0g. Which is exactly what a recoilless rifle does: Gas is vented back to ensure our kosmonauts stay (mostly) put. This mitigates stress on movement control and prevents damage to the pilot and gear from rather harsh acceleration due to firing weapons.
As for ammunition,  why aim at the kosmonaut, if you can use a nuclear warhead? Davey Crocket with its nuclear payload fit all requirements!
Or, if you don't go that large, you might see M18, a 57mm anti-tank grenade launcher, the RMK30 30mm Autocannon or even the the laser-guided Carl Gustav. The latter one even allows chase scenes against the missile zooming in!
Rockets!
And of course, most open tube rocket launchers are recoilless based on... being an open tube that guides the warhead's rocket motor. The force on the shooter is, if well-balanced, neglectable. Many modern versions are MANPATS, though we also swapped to guided munitions, ending with equally low to no recoil ATGM.

As a side note, it might be sometimes useful to actually have recoil on a rifle; although I assume if you can make the rifle recoilless, you can disable that function as well. Also the main combat would already happen inside anything, the outside would get scorched by offenders, as their infantry would need ATS protection, so why not glass the surface while we still can?

Mico-Missiles or Lasers would have practically no recoil
Missiles do not get nearly as much of an advantage as bullets by launching from a tube that is closed in the back.  Many RPGs use open backsides that you hold over your shoulder so that the force of ignition is propelled behind you as the rocket's exhaust instead of into you meaning you only absorb a tiny fraction of the missile's recoil.  If you make the missle right, your only recoil will be from the friction of the exhaust as it leaves the tube resulting in far less recoil even than barrel fired rockets or gyrojets.
Lasers similarly overcome recoil because their wasted energy is absorbed as heat, not kinetic; so, even though you may need to vent some cryogenic fluid to deal with the waste heat, shooting itself will not push you back at all.
They are also better for the engagement ranges you need to deal with.
A big part of the reason that guns are still the go-to weapon system on the ground, is that most fighting happens at ranges of less than 50 meters with lots of cover.  But in 3-dimensional warfare, you will be able to see enemies coming from several km away meaning that most threats will be so far away that bullets will generally be useless against basic evasive actions.  So you need a weapon system that can either course correct in flight like a missile or cover the range too quickly to be avoided like a laser so that you could target enemy troops as they try to drop in from many km away.  Also, while bullets may have infinite range in zero G, inconsistencies in their propellants and barrel geometries limit their target accuracy to a couple of kilometers.
They also avoid their biggest Earth based drawbacks when in space.
The biggest issue on Earth with both weapon systems is weight.  On a modern battlefield, the difference between a 4kg riffle and a 7kg riffle is a big deal, but trying to carry a personal laser weapon or rack of missiles would be prohibitively heavy.  In space you could have a 50kg laser cannon, and be just fine carrying it around places.

Frame challenge: the main infantry combat would go inside an asteroid or a space station
That Boundary game has a significant flaw in it, as described, its combat would happen under sunlight with several asteroids close by. In reality, an asteroid worthy of control would be assailed by ships containing infantry, and its surface could and will be glassed by the ships' weapons, meaning that main fight for actual control should happen inside. The same for a space station, which is already hollow as cheese half eaten by mice. So there would be less directions from where the attacks would come, less need to look around (usually just forward and back), and more obstacles to overcome. Consider that a large asteroid might host a fleet of fighters concealed under its surface, which could pose a threat to an assault ship, with their hangar heavily protected by turrets and moving/movable walls to lock the intruders away. In such environments, the infantry would need totally different kinds of weapons and equipment than what you depict based on the game.

"its surface could and will be glassed by the ships' weapons" <- not necessarily.  The very fact that you are sending in infantry means you are fighting for control, not destruction.  Ships may get involved in an artillery like roll to knock out major strong points and heavy weapons, but they will likely try to conserve their shots just to critical targets.  If you disperse 1000s of cheap infantry across the whole surface, then it may be too expensive to bother trying to wipe them all out with cruise missiles.

Likewise, and infantry assault like this could overwhelm defensive heavy weapons.  Drop 1000s of marines in cheap space suits on a rock protected by million dollar missiles, and they may run out of missiles way faster than you run out of marines.

@Nosajimiki there's no "cheap infantry" in space, there might be "cheap RC drones" but not infantry, living tissue is fragile and requires special care. Also I expect defenders to be armed with rapid fire turrets on the side where ships can't reach - good luck attacking into big dakka! Also modern turrets can prioritize targets, and are able to pinpoint incoming missiles launched by infantry (sub-sonic speeds most likely, as the insides of asteroids are twisted so hard that any attempt to go fast would end in a wall).

You're right however that large numbers can outperform any defense, especially if locked out of supply. Even if there are turrets that fire with deadly accuracy, sending enough meat (or decoys) will exhaust their ammo supply, rendering them useless. The same with other weaponry except lasers, but lasers aren't the weapon of choice even there - too much power into too little effect, even without the atmosphere dispersing the light.

Space suits are only expensive because they are not mass produced.  The actual material cost of a space suit is only a few hundred dollars.  If you were to mass produce millions of them, it would be easy to get their price tag under that of an economy sedan.  As for RC drones, yes, they would be cheaper, but not if you want them to be able to infiltrate a base.  I imagine the first wave would be precision attacks by artillery and drones specifically to take out those turrets, then the infantry would follow it up once all the static/automated defenses are mostly depleted or disabled

Small Calibre munitions
So, no Wind, no gravity means no ballistic trajectory and no discernable decrease in velocity from the Muzzle.
Furthermore, whereas a human hit with a small calibre round (.22lr or .17hmr) can absolutely be fatal, they can also fail to do any meaningful damage to vital organs... in an atmosphere but we are in space - and we do g need to hit a vital organ to kill, we just need to compromise the air tightness of their space suit and let the vacuum of Space do the rest.
For practicality - a smaller round has less recoil leading to less usage of fuel to counteract the effects of firing the weapon. If you want something exotic - .220 Swift would be a great option as it has the highest muzzle velocity (which would be an advantage in space combat)
Other options would be a shotgun type weapon with birdshot (or equivalent) - again the goal is to increase the chance of penetrating the space suit.
But to conclude:
Small light projectiles with small recoil, high muzzle velocity and with enough penetrating power to compromise a space suit.

Birdshot? The penetration difference between that and buckshot is significant - while the latter is devastating effective as an anti-personnel weapon, the former wouldn't be used in that context, ever. Sure, you might get lucky (especially with a close-range blast in the face), but reliable? No way. And if one side has the time to prepare to arm themselves the optimal weapons, then both sides have time to strengthen their suits with whatever Kevlar or ceramics or plate armor works best. Any military grade armor would scoff at birdshot.

@RalphJ - I hear your point - That presumes that the entire space suit can be armored, I am not sure that is reasonable. Assume a full Kevlar weave - it simply needs to be weakened enough to fail catastrophically. In additional Birdshot in an atmosphere slows down a lot more because light weight + drag, which is not a factor in Space.

@TheDemonLord 1 atm between suit and vacuum isn't that much - less than you'd have in an inflated tire. Put a layer of rubbery foam under the armor plates and the foam will be pressed into the opening, sealing it tight.

Keep in mind that even an "un-armored" space suit has 14 layers of material between the astronaut and space with many of those layers being armor grade textiles like Kevlar and Nylon composites. Space suits are designed to resist micrometeor impacts,  so they are already optimized against low mass, high-speed impacts like birdshot.

A crossbow would be an interesting choice:

negligible recoil
easy to repair, and easy to manufacture more bolts without going back to the planet.
bolts can be tipped with explosives, EMP devices, trackers or a grappling wire to reel your kill in.
can double as a grappling gun to anchor yourself to stuff if your thrusters fail
since it would be not powerful enough to punch through the outer shell of a ship, can be used for CQC combat within a ship or a space station without a risk of a hull breach.
(possibly) gets around some legal restrictions on firearms in space, especially if the crossbow is registered as a "grappling hook launcher" or some such, and thus legally not a weapon.


I feel like rate of fire and ammunition weight would be drawbacks for military use, but I like the idea as a personal self-defense weapon.

@user111403, my assumption was that combat over asteroid ownership disputes would be rather low-key, ad-hoc affair with likely less than a dozen of combatants on each side, usually civilian crews taking up arms against pirates and thieves, or occasionally another crew with a conflicting ownership claim, not whole armies of space marines going at it, so they would need only a few shots to end the battle.

Yeah, I absolutely believe that with the right assumptions you can construct a scenario where this is or at least sounds plausible.

Crossbows only have less recoil that assault rifles because they are much weaker than assault rifles.  An average crossbow only has 200J of potential energy compared to ~1800J for a 5.56mm rifle.  If 200j is enough to get a kill shot, you could just switch to .22lr riffles which would give you a LOT more ammo, rate-of-fire, muzzle velocity, accuracy, etc. with the same recoil as a crossbow.  If a .22lr is not enough to get a kill shot, crossbows won't be able to score kill shots either.

A shotgun.
Shotgun pellets on earth suffer from horrible aerodynamic drag reducing their effective range, since space is a near perfect vacuum aerodynamic drag is negligible. You did not state how bulletproof those space suits are is but if they weren't designed with combat in mind a little crack in the helmet or a hole poked in the body is enough to kill, which any grade buckshot will be sufficient in doing so. Looking at a guide I found on the Bass Pro Shops website a cluster of pellets should spread around 8 or 9 feet at 100 meters for a full choke so aiming shouldn't be that hard.
Though you do need to be aware of what's behind your target because newtons first law still applies in space.

As does newton's third law actio est reactio, so shooting tumbles you like hell.

you only need to land a few shots so recoil shouldn't be that bad

While the recoil of a shotgun makes it kind of a dreadful problem, the selection of numerous types of ammunition does partially compensate; especially flechettes. https://smallarmsreview.com/the-history-and-use-of-flechettes-in-ammunition/

while being able to cram more darts than balls in a shotgun shell it still would be less effective since they do need fins to stabilize themselves so theyd likely just tumble and bounce off the space suit. next best thing would probably be a small grade of buck made of tungsten. the little thrusters can compensate for recoil too.

You can not hide deactivate recoil, but action and reaction are not the merciless masters they are made out to be. We already trick them here on the ground, by having a opposit vector counter force applied (recoilless rifle)
In theory, you could delay the recoil, while applying directional changes to it. Now if you have continous fire- and you had a sort of delayed recoil gattling system, you could - in theory, counter future recoil, with the delayed recoil of the past. Its totally harebrained, in need of large masses (thus only making sense in space). But its possible.
An alternative would to convert the energy into rotation, which you then shed as fast spinning disks. Not a viable solution, but in space, direction of spin can be altered for almost free. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_moment_gyroscope
So that leaves you - with some extremely fast spinning mass- which is basically a bomb, in all but name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel
Nobody would bother carrying around huge flywheel disks- but then again, its space. They are not cumbersome once up to speed, they just have that momentum forever..
So 100 shots, and one thrown momentum storage disk..

try turning a spinning wheel... oh right, the momentum counteracts that. It's why bicycles are hard to throw over once the tires are spinning.

Good, point, self-stabilizing gun through recoil- we should charge extra..

angular momentum does not change for free. If you have a great big spinning disk inside your gun, trying to move the gun to track a target will precess you wildly off to the side.

A heavy spinning disc in your gun will make it hell to aim.   Gyroscopes don't just "not fall over" they resist being turned.  After a few shots in zero G, it will no longer be the soldier aiming the gun, but the gun aiming the soldier.

And you can not alter the direction - or simply eject the stored rotation mass?
